# Why do I get a constraint error with UIDatePicker and static UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, static, uidatepicker

I'm building a form to enter data in an application, and I'm using a `UITableView`  built only with static cells, as the fields the user needs to fill won't change. One of these fields is a date. For this field, I'm trying to use a `UIDatePicker` set to `.compact`, so it shows the date in one line, and when the user taps the date a modal calendar will be displayed (new iOS 14 behavior).

The problem is that every time I tap the date (in the simulator), I get the constraint error detailed below:

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<_UISystemBaselineConstraint:0x60000343e3a0 H:[_UIDatePickerLinkedLabel:0x7fb3a0d79f10]-(NSLayoutAnchorConstraintSpace(8))-[UILayoutGuide:0x600002e207e0'']   (active)>",
    "<_UISystemBaselineConstraint:0x60000343e8a0 H:[UILayoutGuide:0x600002e207e0'']-(>=NSLayoutAnchorConstraintSpace(8))-[_UIDatePickerTouchOutsetButton:0x7fb3a0d7acc0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000034373e0 UILabel:0x7fb3a0d7a0d0.trailing <= _UIDatePickerLinkedLabel:0x7fb3a0d79f10.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000034372a0 H:|-(0)-[UILabel:0x7fb3a0d7a0d0]   (active, names: '|':_UIDatePickerLinkedLabel:0x7fb3a0d79f10 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000343e210 _UIDatePickerLinkedLabel:0x7fb3a0d79f10.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x600002e208c0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000343e2b0 H:[_UIDatePickerTouchOutsetButton:0x7fb3a0d7acc0]-(28)-[_UIDatePickerTouchOutsetButton:0x7fb3a0d7afc0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000343e120 _UIDatePickerTouchOutsetButton:0x7fb3a0d7afc0.trailing == UILayoutGuide:0x600002e208c0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003441fe0 UILayoutGuide:0x600002e207e0''.width == UIImageView:0x7fb3a0d7aaf0.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003429950 _UIDatePickerCalendarContentStackView:0x7fb3a0d76c60.width <= _UIDatePickerCalendarView:0x7fb3a0d9e2a0.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003449f40 H:|-(0)-[_UIDatePickerCalendarView:0x7fb3a0d9e2a0]   (active, names: '|':UIDatePicker:0x7fb3a0d23900 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003449ef0 _UIDatePickerCalendarView:0x7fb3a0d9e2a0.trailing == UIDatePicker:0x7fb3a0d23900.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003420190 H:|-(8)-[UIDatePicker:0x7fb3a0d23900]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fb3a0e78db0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000034201e0 UIDatePicker:0x7fb3a0d23900.trailing == UIView:0x7fb3a0e78db0.trailing - 8   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003425ea0 'UISV-canvas-connection' _UIDatePickerCalendarContentStackView:0x7fb3a0d76c60.leading == _UIDatePickerCalendarHeaderView:0x7fb3a0d76df0.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003425f40 'UISV-canvas-connection' H:[_UIDatePickerCalendarHeaderView:0x7fb3a0d76df0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIDatePickerCalendarContentStackView:0x7fb3a0d76c60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003442940 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x7fb3a0e78db0.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000034378e0 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(8)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600002e208c0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIDatePickerCalendarHeaderView:0x7fb3a0d76df0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003437980 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x600002e208c0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(8)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIDatePickerCalendarHeaderView:0x7fb3a0d76df0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000034373e0 UILabel:0x7fb3a0d7a0d0.trailing <= _UIDatePickerLinkedLabel:0x7fb3a0d79f10.trailing   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I've tried to set constraints to the date picker in the static cell, but the error persists. I've also tried leaving the picker without any constraints, without luck.

Any ideas about what could be the issue here? I'm probably doing some basic mistake, but I couldn't identify it.

Environment:

- Swift 5
- iOS 14.x

Comment: Quite often, particularly with "new" UI elements, you'll see **internal** layout warnings / errors. If you search for `_UIDatePickerLinkedLabel` you'll find many related posts.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @DonMag, I'll take a look. I've already searched the web for possible solutions, and noticed other devs had similar issues with the new UIDatePickers. But, unfortunately, I didn't see any details on how to fix this. Often posts suggest moving to an alternate solution, like creating a custom popup view with a picker using the `.inline` option to show the full calendar and then select the date. I wanted to avoid such solution as the new UIDatePicker should provide this functionality out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your error message  UILabel:0x7fb3a0d7a0d0.trailing <= _UIDatePickerLinkedLabel:0x7fb3a0d79f10.trailing   (active)>
I figured out that your Cells label constraint are added to Picker view.

Remove all picker constraints from Cell and make it relative to controllers view.

Comment: The point is that I don't have a label for this UIDatePicker. It is part of the component, so I have no control over it. As far as I understood, when you select the `.compact` type for iOS14, the picker already provides the label for you (that shadowed box with the date). I have only the picker in the cell. And there's no option for aligning the UIDatePicker to the controller, only to the content view, which is the static cell where the picker is.

Comment: @Antonio - we frequently see the same type of *internal layout errors* related to the suggestions bar when the keyboard is displayed. While it is good practice to resolve auto-layout errors/warnings for constraints **you** have created, there's nothing you can do about the internal conflicts.